# Issues with fractions and align

Tags: align, fractions

I'm really new to LaTeX, I only started last week and I'm having an issue with trying to align equations involving fractions. I want to align at the '=' but I am getting errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{Q_{2}}{Q_{1}} 
&= \frac{(1+2i+3j+4k)(1-i-j-k)}{(1+i+j+k)(1-i-j-k)} \\
&= \frac{10+2i+4k}{4} \\
&= \frac{5+i+2}{2}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What error are you seeing?  It compiles fine for me.  Did you remember to `\usepackage{amsmath}`?

Comment: PS: This is were an [”MWE”](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) comes in handy.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding four lines of code to transform your code snippet into an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001). As it stands, the code succeeds in aligning the equations on the respective `=` symbols. Is there something else that's going on that's causing the problem you describe (but which your code, at present, doesn't illustrate)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: I'm using \usepackage{amsmath} and the rest of the code runs fine when I remove this section, it gives errors like Missing $ inserted and Paragraph ended before @\genfrac was complete. thanks very much for your help

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I've managed to get it working now, in my original code there was an extra { that I must have corrected when I asked on here, thanks again!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about some issue which is not shown in the MWE